# Call Python Program from Django Views

Tags: python, django

My Python Program called addName is designed to accept 3 variables (first name, last name, and gender).  How do I call it from Django Views and pass those variables to my Python Program?  It also resides in the same directory as views.py

Will I see the "print" result in the same terminal where I execute "runserver" or I'll have to redirect the output using stdout of some sort?

```
**addName.py**

def webform (firstname, lastname, gender):
    print (firstname, lastname, gender)


**views.py**

from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from userinfo.forms import UserInfo
from addName import webform


# Create your views here.
def addname (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserInfo (request.POST)
        if form.is_valid ():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            firstname = data ['first_name']
            lastname = data ['last_name']
            gender = data ['gender']

            context = {'first_name': firstname, 'last_name': lastname, 'gender': gender}
            webform (firstname, lastname, gender)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect ('/userinfo/results')
            return render (request, 'userinfo/results.html', context)

    else:
        form = UserInfo ()

    return render (request, 'userinfo/addname.html', {'form': form,
            'first_name': request.POST.get ('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': request.POST.get ('last_name', ''),
            })

**addname.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Name</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="gender">
        <span style="color: red;">{{ form.gender.errors }}</span>
        <label for="id_gender_0">Gender:</label>
        {{ form.gender }}
    </div>
    <div class="first_name">
        <span style="color: red;">{{ form.first_name.errors }}</span>
        <label for="id_first_name">First Name:</label>
        {{ form.first_name }}
    </div>
    <div class="last_name">
        <span style="color: red;">{{ form.last_name.errors }}</span>
        <label for="id_last_name">Last Name:</label>
        {{ form.last_name }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Name" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


**results.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted Entries:</h2>
        {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }} {{ gender }}
    <p><a href="{% url "addname" %}">Add more names</a></p>
</body>
</html>


**directory**

user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Python/django-project/django-ab/addressbook/userinfo$ ll
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 5 user user 4096 Dec  4 00:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Nov 24 20:15 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  107 Dec  3 22:35 addName.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   63 Nov 24 20:15 admin.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  306 Nov 24 22:38 forms.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Nov 24 20:15 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Nov 24 23:17 migrations/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   57 Nov 24 20:15 models.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec  4 00:16 __pycache__/
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Nov 24 20:35 templates/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   60 Nov 24 20:15 tests.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  416 Dec  3 21:24 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  986 Dec  4 00:16 views.py
```

Comment: 1. _How do I call it from Django Views and pass those variables to my Python Program?_ I see that you have done an import and done a subsequent call. I think that is way to go.

2. _Will I see the "print" result in the same terminal where I execute "runserver" or I'll have to redirect the output using stdout of some sort?_ It should print in the same terminal which is stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input.  I figured it out.

I changed

```
from addName import webform
```

to

```
from userinfo.addName import webform
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll see the "print" result in the same terminal where you execute "runserver" . Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I did but I ran into an "Import Error" - No module named 'addName' from line 4 in views.py.  Did I import it incorrectly?

Comment: @dreamzboy I tried, it worked for me. Did your dir has the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: That's odd.  Yep, my directory does have __init__.py with nothing inside.

Comment: How about `tree` it and see the full structure.

Comment: userinfo
|___migrations
|___templates
|_____init__.py
|___addName.py
|___admin.py
|___forms.py
|___models.py

Comment: Please post it in the question with a format. ^_^. And looks like your `__init__.py` is in the wrong place.You should put your `__init__.py` in userinfo not in `templates`.

Comment: It's kind of difficult displaying the tree with this text box only showing everything in-line so you'll have to take my words for it.  The app folder is called [userinfo] inside this folder there are [migrations],[templates], __init__.py, addName.py, admin.py, forms.py, models.py, tests.py, urls.py, and views.py.  All the files after the templates folder are directly inside [userinfo].

Answer (score 0):

you can call your method

from your views

like

```
 test_method(f_name,l_name,gendre)
```

and use

```
from  filename import test_method
```

at top

yes it will show all your print statement at terminal .

Comment: I think I already did that.  My method is called "webform" and I imported as "from addName import webform".

Comment: so it is not calling your addName webform method?

Comment: I received an "Import Error" - No module named 'addName' from line 4 in views.py.  It's working now.  See my comment above/below =)